# Annotation doctrine ManyToOne

Tags: symfony, annotations, doctrine

I have one class B with 4 array collection :

```
class B {
    private $FWs;
    private $FXs;
    private $FYs;
    private $FZs;

    ...
}
```

Each class FW, FX, FY, FZ extend an other abstract class F.

I would like to do this :

```
b->getFWs();
b->getFXs();
b->getFYs();
b->getFZs();

fw->getB();
fx->getB();
fy->getB();
fz->getB();
```

I don't know which annotation should i put :

```
abstract class F {
    /**
     * @OMR\ManyToOne(targetEntity="B", inversedBy= ? )
     */
     private $b;
}

class B {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity= ?, mappedBy="b")
     */
    private $FWs;

    ...
}
```

Can you help me. Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set $b as protected in your abstract classe, annotations set on children will be added to parent annotations.

(If someone arrive here and want to override annotations he has to do it like it is explained [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses.html))

Just define your ManyToOne relations in your children classes :

```
abstract class F {
     protected $b;
}

class FW extends F{
    /**
     * @OMR\ManyToOne(targetEntity="B", inversedBy= "FWs" )
     */
     protected $b;
}

class FX extends F {
    /**
     * @OMR\ManyToOne(targetEntity="B", inversedBy= "FXs" )
     */
     protected $b;
}

...

class B {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity= "FW", mappedBy="b")
     */
    private $FWs;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity= "FX", mappedBy="b")
     */
    private $FXs;

    ...
}
```